# When using Popups with a datatemplate, do I need a ViewModel for each datatemplate?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, popup

The short background is I'm taking text from the user with the use of a Popup window.  I have several types of data I am taking in.  An easy example is: Name, Address, and Contact Info.  All in the same Popup window but at different times.  When the user selects the button for Name, the Popup displays "First" "Middle" "Last"..or if they select the Address button, the Popup displays "Street" "City" "State"..so on and so forth..I have datatemplates that I'm applying to the Popup to generate the UI elements needed.  Do I need ViewModels for each datatemplate?  In the end I compile all the info into a text file via a main view which already has a ViewModel associated with it.

Comment: are First(name), Last(name), Street, City etcproperties on the main VM?

Comment: @AwkwardCoder The Popup will parse the First, Middle and Last names with a '|' and that text will be placed in the main view model